# Is there a React Native utility for drag-to-expand panels?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a React Native App (using Expo) and I’m trying to implement a map/search layout similar to what is in Yelp or many other location-based hybrid map/search views (eg I checked all of the food related apps on my phone :slight_smile: McDonalds, Starbucks, DoorDash):

[image: yelp map search UI]

Specifically, I’m curious how to create that sort of draggable panel from the bottom, where you can drag it so that it overlaps the map.

Yelp/DoorDash technically have 3 states for this bottom panel: a completely collapsed state, an intermediate (default) state, and a completely expanded state, and you can even flick from completely collapsed to completely expanded.

Is there a standardized way to accomplish this with React Native? (I'm a little out-of-touch with the RN ecosystem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, here's a third party library where this behavior is implemented, and even the example in the documentation is off a map searchview. https://github.com/octopitus/rn-sliding-up-panel